# Fixing Negative Values in the Land Cover Analysis using the SCP plugin on QGIS

Tags: qgis, scp

I am using the SCP plugin to classify land cover on QGIS 3. I am having some success but there are some issues that I am slowly working through. One of the biggest issues is that I am getting values that are transparent in my raster and with a negative value (-1000). I am not sure what has caused this but it seems that it may be a result of different classifications having a similar spectral signature? When I reduce the number of land classes it seems to remedy this to a degree, but as a result I am not able to classify some important vegetation types. See image below:

[image: Also]

Also, what is the best way to reduce the amount of unclassified land covers (shown in black)? I am assuming make more ROIs?

Comment: One question per Question, please.